# Include code snippet which is licensed under the MIT License in a paper

Tags: publications, citations, copyright, license

My paper is about a software I created which uses part of another software licensed under the MIT license. It is available on Github and includes a copy of the MIT license correctly. Additionally the paper cites the repository.

I want to to include a code snippet of the other software in my paper, but the code is licensed on Github with the MIT License.

Currently I include the code and cite the source for it, is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: "Snippet" is slightly ambiguous. The most relevant question is whether the excerpt is small enough to fall under fait use/fair dealings protections or not.

Comment: With snippet I meant ~10-15 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) is very permissive. You can certainly do what you suggest.

Quoting:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

Comment: I'm not so concerned about the usage but the need to include the MIT License in all subsequent uses of the software because I didn't want to append it to my paper. Quote: `The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.` But I guess it's easy to argue that its not a substantial portion.

Comment: @J.Schneider, you don't need to quote the license text. Just name the version that covers the code. "MIT v4 license" or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

> Currently I include the code and cite the source for it, is there anything more I need to do?

In my opinion, No. You are basically citing some code that you used in your research, but did not write. Link to the source code on GitHub. You are effectively telling people you did not write this code and are 'giving credit' to the original author.